# Not able to execute echo within legacy in Shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, echo

Below is my code and I am able to get the ssh connection. But after that it is doing nothing.

```
log_time="date +%F\%T"
PR_ONE="username@hostname"
file="/home/log.txt"
to_list="myemail"
echo "`$log_time`" >> $file
`ssh $PR_ONE "echo df -hP | grep fs1 | awk '{print $4}'"` >> $file
cat $file | mailx -s "Disk space usages" $to_list
```

I am getting the email but only with `$log_time`. I know that I am doing something wrong in quotations in the `ssh` line.

I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: *Prefer use `$(...)` instead of backquote*

Comment: What is the `i` after the awk command ?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It is a typo actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo "df -hP | grep fs1 | awk '{print $4}'" | ssh -tt $PR_ONE >> $file
```

or prefer this :

```
ssh -tt $PR_ONE << EOF >> $file
df -hP | grep fs1 | awk '{print $4}'
EOF
```

Comment: The first command worked. But I got a warning message as `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` during the execution. Also what I am getting is `/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-fs2vol                               7.4T  6.4T  593G  92% /net/si-091l/fs1`, but I want is `$4` of `awk` which is `593G` alone.

Comment: use `ssh -tt` to force pseudo-tty allocation